# Float in if statements returns negative instead given value

Tags: c, return-value, function-definition

Hello I am learning C and I am confused why this certain line returns -126.00 instead of 130.00

here is the source code:

```
char course1(char course, float price){

    if(course == 'E' || course == 'e') {
        printf("You have taken PHP!\n");
        price = 130.00;
        return price; //returns -126.00
    }
    else
        printf("Invalid!\n");
    return 0;
}
```

```
int main() {  
   char course;
   float totalCourse;
   float y = 0;
   scanf(" %c", &course);
   totalCourse += course1(course, y);
   printf("In main, the total is %.2f", totalCourse);

   return 0;
}
```

When I run the code, and inputs 'E' C returns -126 instead of 130 as given in the source code. Can anyone explain why it happens?

Comment: Because you return `char` for some reason.

Comment: Also `totalCourse` is uninitialized

Comment: Unrelated to your problem: Don't use `float` for monetary values. It doesn't follow the math you expect when counting money. Using `double` is a little bit less bad, but still bad. Use integers, and count cents.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The data type `char` is commonly `signed`, as it is in your case. A `signed char` typically has a range from -128 to +127.

You assign the value 130 to such a data type. By the commonly used two's complement, the value 130 is "wrapped around":

- ...
- 127 -> +127
- 128 -> -128
- 129 -> -127
- **130 -> -126**

**Edit:**

You can also calculate the resulting value, if you subtract the number of possible values from an input above the range, or add to an input below the range. For the typical `char` this number is 2<sup>8</sup> = 256, and you get 130 - 256 = -126.

Use your mathematical skills to bring this in a general formula. ;-)

Answer (score 1):

For starters the parameter `price` is not used within the function. That is its value is ignored.

```
char course1(char course, float price){

    if(course == 'E' || course == 'e') {
        printf("You have taken PHP!\n");
        price = 130.00;
        return price; //returns -126.00
    }
    else
        printf("Invalid!\n");
    return 0;
}
```

Secondly the function has the return type `char` instead of `float`. It should at least have the return type `float`.

Apart from this the variable `totalCourse` was not initialized.

```
float totalCourse;
```

So this compound assignment operator `+=`

```
totalCourse += course1(course, y);
```

invokes undefined behavior.